# Does NSStringFromClass([MyEntityClass class]) generate a safe Core Data Entity name?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsstring

Most (all I've seen) Core Data tutorials use the following code snippet with `@"MyEntityClass"` hard-coded in:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntityClass"];
```

**Is it safe to use `NSStringFromClass()` as an Entity Name?**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([MyEntityClass class])];
```

This seams to be much easer to deal with regarding refactoring and the like. Especially since I am having Xcode create my `NSManagedObject` subclasses. I ask because I have never seen this before, so perhaps I am missing something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that code is fine, *if* your entity's class is set to `MyEntityClass` in your model.

I prefer to give the entity class a class method that returns the entity name:

```
+ (NSString *)entityName {
    return NSStringFromClass(self);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[MyEntityClass entityName]];
```

This way, if I want to change the class name without changing the entity name in the model, I can just make the change in the class method:

```
+ (NSString *)entityName {
    return @"NewEntityName";
}
```

Why would I do that?  Well, I might decide on a better name for the entity.  Changing the class name doesn't break compatibility with an existing Core Data persistent store, but changing the entity name in the model file does.  I can change the class name, and the `entityName` method, but leave the entity name unchanged in the model, and then I don't have to worry about migration.  (Lightweight migration supports renamed entities so it's not that big of a deal either way.)

You could go further and actually have the `entityName` method look up the entity name from the managed object model at runtime.  Suppose your application delegate has a message that returns the managed object model:

```
+ (NSString *)entityName {
    static NSString *name;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        NSString *myName = NSStringFromClass(self);
        NSManagedObjectModel *model = [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication delegate] managedObjectModel];
        for (NSEntityDescription *description in model.entities) {
            if ([description.managedObjectClassName isEqualToString:myName]) {
                name = description.name;
                break;
            }
        }
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException
            format:@"no entity found that uses %@ as its class", myName];
    });
    return name;
}
```

Obviously, if you really want to do this, you should factor out the contents of the `dispatch_once` block into a helper method, probably on your app delegate (or wherever you get the model).

Comment: If you don't want to go so far as to add the extra lookup code, you can add this assert before any internal accesses to `entityName:`. `NSAssert(context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName[[‌​self entityName]] != nil, @"Entity with name %@ not found in model. Is your class name the same as your entity name?", [self entityName]);` This will issue you an error at runtime if your model's entity name doesn't match your class' name.

Comment: in this case you have to add code to category of every auto generated object? just concerned about to create new file for classes to add only this function.

Comment: @VitaliK You could add a category to `NSManagedObject`, but if you do so, don't name it `entityName` as that's too generic.  Use a prefix, like `Vitali_entityName` to avoid name collisions.

Comment: For others finding this answer, another option is to use mogenerator which will create that function for you.