# Core Data: How to create a Managed Object without referencing the entity by string

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

To improve the readability of my code, I have been generating Core Data classes for my entities so I can access them using getters and setters (I personally use the dot notation) rather than `setValue: forKey:`

For example, instead of `[aDateObject setValue:nameString forKey:@"name"];`

I will use: `aDateObject.name = nameString;`

I was wondering if there is an equivalent approach for inserting a new managed object into the managed object context.  For example, I currently create a new `DateTimeFlightDataType` with the following:

```
    aDateObject = (DateTimeFlightDataType*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DateTimeFlightDataType"
                                                                         inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Is there a way to create and insert this object into the context using my class (`DateTimeFlightDataType`) rather than the entity string name for consistency?

Comment: I think a good approach is 'start using Mogenerator' :) it will give you the classes as well as methods to avoid use of string constants.

Comment: Fair enough, and I see a lot of talk about using Mogenerator (including some recommendations to avoid it).  It may be more heavyweight than I really need and winds up adding another dependency that, if not required, I'd rather avoid, which is why I'm looking to see if there is a native way to do this.

Comment: A category on NSManagedObject that uses NSStringFromClass would work - I'm not at my mac ATM so wouldn't like to type in sample code on the phone...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049592/does-nsstringfromclassmyentityclass-class-generate-a-safe-core-data-entity-n for examples using `NSStringFromClass` and alternative solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write:

```
NSString *name = NSStringFromClass([DateTimeFlightDataType class]);
NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = self.managedObjectContext;
aDateObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name 
                                            inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
```

Comment: Thank you.  Makes sense - same method call, we're just getting the string name from the class.  It decouples the entity name from the class as well (if that would ever be important).  In the end, it actually makes the code a little harder to follow, for me at least (I am new to iOS programming) but this is almost certainly the right way to do it if you're trying to avoid making direct references to the entity.

Comment: The good thing about this is that you are safe against typos, refactoring gets easier too.

Comment: I would have to concur with that.  I am teaching a friend on using Core Data as we go (as well as patterns) and am trying to keep things as simple "looking" as I can.  But I think this would be my preferred approach from a decoupling, refactoring standpoint.

Comment: I like this approach, but it's obviously not going to work if you have different names for your classes and entities.

Comment: +1 Because this is a good way to insert a new entity dynamically.  But, under normal circumstances, this (in my opinion) is less readable than just passing in a string with the entity name...

Answer (score 1):

creating a MO always requires an entity and these are always defined by a string.

the common approach is to somehow make it so the string doesn't need to be hardcoded but can be derived from the MO's class.. typically using `NSStringFromClass`

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote up, or I would mark this as useful!