# Obtaining entity name from NSMangedObject subclass class object

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is there a bulit-in way to obtain an entity name from the class object of an NSManagedObjectSubclass?  I know that this can be readily determined from an instance of a subclass, but I want to ask the class itself.  I can write a class function, but I would rather do this introspectively.

Comment: There is no built-in method, but this answer provides a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049649/1187415

Comment: thanks.  my class names are not the same as my entityNames, so I've not used this approach:  for now, i'm just passing constant strings from a class function adopted by all my classes.

Comment: The `entityName` class method from rob mayoff's answer is exactly for that case: it retrieves the entity name from the entity descriptions in the core data model.

Comment: you are right; i didn't look past what he did at the top.  thanks

Comment: If you are happy with that answer we can close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049592/does-nsstringfromclassmyentityclass-class-generate-a-safe-core-data-entity-n.

Comment: ok;  go ahead and close it

Answer (score 8):

You can do it now by executing `NSManagedObject.entity().name` where `NSManagedObject()` is your subclass.

Comment: Which is actually optional and is not a reliable source. I've had multiple occasions where .entity().name returned nil while I invoked it on a subclass of NSManagedObject that should've had an entity. I would not recommend relying on this.

Comment: It returns optional, so you always need to check a provided value before unwrapping. You could propose other ways to get that name.

Comment: @Vasily mark is right. For some strange reason nil is returned by `.name`. And if you are going to check before unwrapping and then passing the alternative, you might as well just specify the alternative in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Check out mogenerator if you haven't already. 
http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/

It adds a lot of missing features to core data. In particular it keeps you from having to regenerate your entity classes.

You could iterate thru the key values of the entities in the context:

[managedObjectContext registeredObjects];